# How to select a date from calendar in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to automate price line website and trying to select the date range. But unable to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two way i can think of to select date from calendar.

First way and easy way:

If date field is a `textbox` or if you can set the date using selenium `sendKeys` , you can go for `sendkeys` itself to select the date. Just make sure the format of input.

Second way:

You have the build the logic to select the date, i can suggest one way to select date here,

1. First format the input date(your input) as day , month and year.
2. Select the year first(it's depends on the application like selecting from dropdown or click left and right arrow , etc...).
3. Go for the month next and then day.

   - you can still put some condition while selecting the date for example, checking date is not disable before selecting it.

Comment: Pradeep, SendKeys method is not working here. Can you open the URL and see it once. Here From and to dates are need to be passed at a time. if you have some code snippet share here. Thanks